# Почему у меня не сохраняются данные в БД?

Tags: c#

У меня есть две сущности категория и подкатегория. Они имеют отношение один ко многим.

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly ICollection<Subcategory> _subcategories = new List<Subcategory>();

    private Category()
    {

    }

    public Category(string name)
    {
        SetName(name);
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories => _subcategories.AsEnumerable();

    public void SetSubcategories(IEnumerable<Subcategory> subcategories)
    {
        foreach (Subcategory subcategory in subcategories)
        {
            if (subcategory != null)
            {
                _subcategories.Add(subcategory);
            }
        }
    }

    protected internal void SetName(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Subcategory : BaseValueObjectsWithId
{
    private Subcategory()
    {

    }

    public Subcategory(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

Я создаю сущность категории добавляя сразу подкатегории

```
        Category category = new(request.Name);

        if (request.Subcategories != null)
        {
            category.SetSubcategories(new []{new Subcategory(request.Subcategories.First().Name)});
        }

        await _categoryService.CreateCategoryAsync(category, cancellationToken);

        return new CreateCategoryResponse(category.Id);
```

И получается так, что в методе репозитория я вижу, что у меня сущность такая какая должна быть, но в бд добавляется только категория, а её подкатегории нет

```
        public Task<int> CreateAsync(T objectWithId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _dataContext.Entry(objectWithId).State = EntityState.Added;

        _dataContext.Set<T>().Add(objectWithId);

        return _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_dataContext.Entry(objectWithId).State = EntityState.Added;` - эта строка лишняя.

Смотрим документацию Accessing Tracked Entities. Раздел [Working with the entity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/entity-entries#working-with-the-entity). Цитата:

> Unlike in EF6, setting the state of an individual entity will not cause all connected entities to be tracked. This makes setting the state this way a lower-level operation than calling Add, Attach, or Update, which operate on an entire graph of entities.

То есть, когда вы вручную изменяете `State`, не происходит отслеживание всех подкатегорий. Если оставить только вызов метода `Add`, это произойдёт автоматически.